# Integrating $\int\frac{\cos(\omega t)\gamma e^{-\gamma t}}{\omega}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate
$$\int\frac{\cos(\omega t)\gamma e^{-\gamma t}}{\omega}dt,$$
where $\gamma, \omega \neq 0$.

I tried using substitution $u=\omega t$, $du=\omega dt$ and got $\frac{1}{\omega^2} \int \cos(u) \gamma e^{-\frac{\gamma u}{\omega}} du$ and then integrating by parts, but so far it seems like an endless cycle of substitutions and ind integration by parts, and I can't get to something meaningful. Is there any easy way to compute this?

**Edit:** Using one of the hints, I arrived at $\frac\gamma\omega\mathrm{Re}\left[\frac{\mathrm{e}^{(i\omega-\gamma)t}}{i\omega-\gamma}+C\right]$, but not sure how do go from here. Have I made any errors here (I am not sure about the denominator)?

Comment: Hint: $\cos x=(e^{i x}+e^{-ix})/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for $a,b$

$$
\begin{align}
I=\int\cos(ax)e^{bx}&={\sin(ax)\over a}e^{bx}-{b\over a}\int\sin(ax)e^{bx}\\
&={\sin(ax)\over a}e^{bx}+{b\cos(ax)\over a^2}-{b^2\over a^2}\int \cos(ax)e^{bx}\\&={e^{bx}(a\sin(ax)+b\cos(ax))\over a^2}-{b^2\over a^2}I
\end{align}
$$

The on rearrangement gives

$$
\int\cos(ax)e^{bx}={e^{bx}\over a^2+b^2}(b\cos(ax)+a\sin(ax))+C
$$

Edit:
$$\int{\cos(\omega t)\gamma e^{-\gamma t}\over \omega}\\
={\gamma\over\omega}\int\cos(\omega t)e^{-\gamma t}\\
={\gamma\over\omega}{e^{-\gamma x}\over \omega^2+\gamma^2}(\omega\sin(\omega x)-\gamma\cos(\omega x))$$

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure I get this. I got $\int\ \cos(\omega t)\gamma e^{-\gamma t}dt=\frac{e^{-\gamma t}}{\omega^2+\gamma^2}(\gamma\cos(\omega t)+\omega\sin(\omega t))+C$, but the original integral has also $\omega$ in the denominator. How does this work?

Comment: $\gamma,\omega$ are constants right? You can take them outside integral with no issue

Comment: Oh yeah right my bad, thanks

Answer (score 2):

We firstly take off the constant and get
$I=\frac{\gamma}{\omega} \int \cos (\omega t) e^{-\gamma t} d t.$
$$
\begin{aligned}\int \cos (\omega t) e^{-\gamma t} d t = & \Re \int e^{\omega t i} e^{-\gamma t} d t \\
= & \Re \int e^{(\omega i-\gamma) t} d t \\
= & \Re\left(\frac{e^{(\omega i-\gamma)t}}{\omega i-\gamma}+ C\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

where $C $ is a complex constant.

By rationalisation, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{e^{(\omega i-\gamma)t}}{\omega i-\gamma} & =-\frac{e^{(\omega i-\gamma)t}}{\gamma-\omega i} \cdot \frac{\gamma+\omega i}{\gamma+\omega i} \\
& =-\frac{e^{-\gamma t}}{\gamma^2+\omega} e^{\omega i}(\gamma+\omega i)
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence we get$$
\Re\left(\frac{e^{(\omega i-\gamma)t}}{\omega i-\gamma}\right)=-\frac{e^{-\gamma t}}{\gamma^2+\omega^2}(\gamma \cos \omega t-\omega \sin \omega t)
$$
and arrive at
$$
\boxed{I=\frac{\gamma e^{-\gamma t}}{\omega(\gamma^2+\omega^2)}(\omega \sin \omega t-\gamma  \cos \omega t)+k}
$$
where $k=\Re {(C)}$ is a real constant.

Comment: I like your solution, thanks